# SWT built-in Unix Terminal

Tags: java, ssh, swt

Is there an option in Java SWT to open SSH terminal window and give the user the ability to run all the unix Command.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick google returned this: http://www.sshtools.co.uk/terminal-components/index.html which looks a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)

It is a pure Java implementation of SSH2. It will be more compatible than using an OS-bound SSH shell

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,
I already take a look on it before but is it support working with SWT and can open the terminal as window.